# How to downsize images by percentage of themselves without using transform: scale()

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a number of horizontally distributed and equally spaced logos (parent container set as `display: flex`, `justify-content: space-between`). So they can fit on the screen as viewport decreases, I scale them down using `transform: scale()`: that's not good because although the logos themselves are downsized, the space they normally take is preserved so they appear more and more apart from each other (in particular the far left and far right logos don't touch the edges of their parent container any more).

Catch: unlike the simplified markup below, my setup includes `<li>` element that are hidden by CMS and it's not possible to know in advance which ones will be visible and which ones will be hidden.

Any way around this problem?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="image1.jpg" />          
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="image2.jpg" />          
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="image3.jpg" />          
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="image4.jpg" />          
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No problem, I edited my question to add some code.

Comment: Why you do not set the images size by view port percentage?

Comment: Because they vary in size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max-width: 100%` on the images themselves to constrain them. Then use margin on the `<li>`s to space them.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*
  justify-content: space-around; <-- you might try this instead 
  */
}
li {
  /*margin: 0 5px; no-no for OP use case*/
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 96%; /* the margin workaround */
}

/* demo cleanup only */
ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" />          
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" />          
  </li>
  <!-- 
  <li></li>
  Oops, missing LI. -->
  <li>
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" />          
  </li>
</ul>
```

Need to hit the 'Full Page' button when you run the snippet to test how it scales.

**Edit re: no LI margin:** You can move the margin to the images in a few different ways. Here, since the `<li>` has `text-align: center` already, just reducing the max-width on the image should suffice. Also means the LIs will collapse completely. New HTML has a missing image.

Comment: Good answer! Just to make it clear, the key here is that flex-shrink is 1 by default, so the li decrease the size if necesary

Comment: Thanks. But in my particular setup some images/logos are hidden and I don't know which ones in advance. So I can't set a margin-left of 0 and a margin-right of 0 on first and last logos. So the solution cannot rely on margins... I should have mentioned that in my question sorry. Just edited it.

Comment: @drake035 Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But I think we're moving away from the problem. Some li elements are hidden in my setup (not just the images). Also in your example the images end up not being equally spaced. I'll accept your answer though because max-width and margins did the trick. For dealing with hidden items I used jQuery, there's probably no choice.

Comment: @drake035 Missed that spacing error. One the LI is hidden (instead of the image), image spacing is even again. Updated again.